# Appium iOS can't inspect notification layer

Tags: selenium, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

Im using Appium to test my notifications in my iOS app.
Im sending with another device a notification while the iOS app is in BG. Then I swipe down using :

```
        ((IOSDriver) wd).swipe(500,0,500,1000,1000);
```

The above works, the screen get scrolled down and I can physically see the notification. The issue is that the appium still inspects the screen below.
I checked appium inspector and it verified that it doesn't recognize nothing but the elemnts of the layer below the notifications one.

Any approach ??

Comment: have you checked "adb shell dumpsys window windows" ?

Comment: @pankajmishra can you elaborate please ?

Comment: The above command gives all the details about current screen on focus, so u will get the details about notification

Comment: Sounds awesome ! how do I run it inside a java code ?

Comment: First check out manually by running this command on command prompt and see if u r getting the result or not

Comment: I get empty results, but when I run "adb devices" its also empty... It's weird because im able to run tests on that iphone device.

Comment: Just restart your devices, check USB configuration  etc

Comment: I cant' make it work. we are talking about iOS or Android ?

Comment: My apologies I thought adb should run on for iOS devices as well ,but for iOS it is XCRUN, the only tip I can give u now is to check equivalent command in XCRUN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that fits my needs.

I found out that if I click the home button and then swipe down the notification are visible to Appium.
Because Appium not having key events for iOS, iPhone has the an accessibility option for home button, I toggled that on and I can simply click it during the test and swipe down the notification center.

I know it's not ideal but its working.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know it is **known limitation** for iOS now.

You can get notification bar elements on [Android only](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/OpenNotificationsTest.java)

But based on [top comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537678/xcuitest-interact-with-a-notification-banner) it should be possible to wrap up with Appium since Xcode 9 introduced interaction with multiple apps, so its matter of time.

Comment: I succeed doing it before, but I messed up something and I cant redo it. Any advice ?

Comment: If you can provide the code that was working previously => smb might help you. But as I said it is not supported by Appium (that use XCUITest for iOS 9.3+) so not sure what actually you were able to get.