# Appium iOS can't go to Home screen

Tags: ios, homescreen, appium-ios, home-button

Im using Appium to test my iOS app on real device.
During the test I need to go to the home screen (I must do so) but can't find a way to do it.

I found here that there is an option to use the accessibility for Home button- 
[Appium iOS can't inspect notification layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006973/appium-ios-cant-inspect-notification-layer/48761711#48761711)

but how can I click on this? Appium doesn't recognized this button.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using **[Appium Java client](https://github.com/appium/java-client)** you can switch to Home screen on iOS the same way as on Android:

`driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(-1));`

Answer (score 0):

You should run:

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: pressButton", ImmutableMap.of("name", "home"));
```

Look at [this](https://appiumpro.com/editions/68-automating-physical-buttons-on-ios-devices) post.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: pressButton", ImmutableMap.of("name", "home"));
```

Note: driver must be of type AppiumDriver, if not you need to cast it